# Do I need to archive postgres WAL records if I am already streaming them to a standby server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a postgres master node which is streaming WAL records to a standby slave node. The slave database runs in read only mode and has a copy of all data on the master node. It can be switched to master by creating a recovery.conf file in /tmp.

On the master node I am also archiving WAL records. I am just wondering if this is necessary if they are already streamed to the slave node? The archived WAL records are 27GB at this point. The disk will fill eventually.

Comment: Archiving them from the master should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standby server is no backup; it only protects you from hardware failure on the primary.

Just imagine that somebody by mistakes deletes data or drops a table, then you won't be able to recover from this problem without a backup.

Create a job that regularly cleans up archived WALs if they exceed a certain age.

Comment: I already have a daily backup though. So I guess I just need WAL records from the last 2 days at most? So if I have a backup from 12pm, and the failure occured at the 4pm, then I could take the 12pm backup and replay transactions for the 4 hours between 12pm and 4pm. At the moment I have every single WAL record from when the database was initially provisioned.

Comment: Yes, sure, if two days is enough for you, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a full backup, then you can purge the preceding WAL files associated.
The idea is to preserve the WAL Files for PITR in case if your server crashes.

If your Primary server crashes, then you can certainly use your hot-standby and make it primary, but at this time you have to build another server (as a hot-standby). Typically you don't want to build it using streaming replication.

You will be using full backup+wal backups to build a server and then proceed further instead of relying on streaming replication.